# jquery div refresh with included PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using this code to constantly refresh divs with PHP included files in:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function() {
     $('#ContentLeft').load('live_stats1.php').fadeIn("slow");
     $('#ContentRight').load('live_stats2.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 2000);

});
```

my HTML looks like:

```
<div id="ContentLeft">
<?php include 'live_stats1.php'; ?>
</div>

<div id="ContentRight">
<?php include 'live_stats2.php'; ?>
</div>
```

When i look in the console in Google Chrome is shows the live_stat1.php and live_stats2.php pages constantly loading, will this cause problems as they are constantly refreshing and slow down the internet/use a lot of bandwidth on the internet connection it is running on?

Comment: This seems an inefficient way to update a page.  Read up on node.js to see other ways to update a page in real time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the amount of processing that is being done in `live_stats1.php` and `live_stats2.php`  I'm guessing because you are loading stats of some kind you may be doing quite a few database queries in those scripts.

I think 2 second is a very short interval and I would think about increasing this.  Do someone benchmarking on how long those scripts take to complete and find the optimum interval time.

As you are using `.load()` you could think about adding a callback when its complete and set a variable.  Then on each loop your could check to see if the previous load has finished.  Because there is no point trying to keep loading a script that hasn't had time to finish

```
var contentLeftLoaded = true;
var contentRightLoaded = true;
setInterval(function() {

    //Has content loaded from previous request
    if(contentLeftLoaded) {
        contentLeftLoaded = false;
        $('#ContentLeft').load('live_stats1.php', function() {
            $('#ContentLeft').fadeIn("slow");
            contentLeftLoaded = true;
        });
    }
    if(contentRightLoaded) {
        contentRightLoaded = false;
        $('#ContentRight').load('live_stats2.php', function() {
            $('#ContentRight').fadeIn("slow");
            contentRightLoaded = true;
        });
    }
}, 2000);
```